# Delete database records using jquery ajax in asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to delete database records using jquery ajax. When click delete button popup message appear and when confirm it i got error message The resource cannot be found and Requested url:/Category/Delete/8. i wrote a separate js file name category.js

**CategoryController.cs**

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        _categoryService.Delete(id);
        //return RedirectToAction("Index");
        return Json(Url.Action("Index"));
    }
```

**Category.js**

```
function Delete(id) {

  var ans = confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this Record?");
  debugger
  if (ans) {

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/Category/Delete" + id,
          success: function (response) {
              alert("Successfully Deleted");
              window.location.href = response;
          }
      })
  }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
<td>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Update", new { id = category.CategoryID }, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = category.CategoryID }, new { @class = "btn btn-danger", @onclick = "Delete('" + category.CategoryID + "');" })
</td>
```

Comment: the URL should have id as part of it and separate it with a / ? url: "/Category/Delete/" + id

Comment: 1) You are missing a slash on the `url:` line.  Should be `url: "/Category/Delete/" + id`.  2) You are not sending over the anti-forgery token so you may not want to call `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` from your controller action method.

Answer (score 0):

as Id is a parameter sent via the URL, so I think it should be an HTTP GET request?

Maybe you can try it with a GET...